# Is there any API documentation for CIFS like we have for JCIFS

Tags: smb

I want to use CIFS for creating smbclient, but there is no good documentation available similar to a very very good API documentation for JCIFS.

http://jcifs.samba.org/src/docs/api/

I tried downloading libsmbclient, libsmbclient-dev, but no docs. Is there any c++ binding for JCIFS as a last resort!

Answer (score 0):

You can download the documentation from this link:

https://sites.google.com/site/adnankamili/

It has been created using doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for general information about the SMB protocol, this repository may be helpful: ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/developr/drg/CIFS/

Specifically, ftp://ftp.microsoft.com/developr/drg/CIFS/cifs9f.doc contains an accessible explanation of the protocol, especially for network engineer type people.